# Azure DSC Configurations

Tags: azure

I was wondering if there is a way to create local accounts on a virtual machine by using DSC Configuration so that I dont have to create it one by one. Current I use DSC Configuration to install IIS and .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible via the [User DSC resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/userresource)

Comment: Thanks. I found the answer just now.